# How to beat Terran by another Terran if he FE with following factory?

Tags: starcraft-2, starcraft-terran

Few days ago **in TvT** I've seen a good implementation of the terran FE strategy. It was something like this:

- 9 Supply;
- 11 Rax (pump marines);
- 13 Rax (pump marines);
- 14(15) gas;
- 15 OC;
- once have enough gas build 1-2 TechLabs;
- once have money build CC;
- once have enough gas build Factory, pump tanks, research siege mode.

I consider this as a pretty good opening that is hard to be beaten by other Terran strategy:
- you will have enough marines to defend against avarage push (Definitely, you need to scout and for case if opponent does MegaRax you need to delay CC and build 1-2 more Rax till you don't have tanks);
- you will have own tanks a little bit later then your opponent, but taking into account distance, you will have marines to hold push, and you will have own tanks pretty soon to deny push;
- you will be also defended against Banshee rush: having enough marines and two CC (each with OC) you can be relatively easy defend yourself.

Last time in TvT I play the following strategy and it seems workable for me (at least against opponent of my strength).

**Question**:
What is a weakness of that strategy? How could I beat that myself if play against other Terran when detect that he is going to FE?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Weakness/Winning Counter:** Short Answer Helions (w/BlueFlame) and Banshees.

A counter build like this was featured the other day on [Day9 dailies (#258)](http://day9tv.blip.tv/file/4745995/). He has an excellent video up interviewing the guy who perfected this TvT counter build. The build is fairly technical but doesn't require exceptional APM with its weakness possibly being Thors.

**Summary:** Helions roar in devastate the marines, and Banshees cleanup the Tanks as Helions retreat. This build only requires 2Port 2Fact for a long time, reducing the need for other production buildings. It seems a key to this build you should maintain air superiority.

Basic build goes something like this (Taken from iEchoic's post):

- 10 supply
- 12 rax
- 13 ref
- 15 OC
- 15 make one marine, then queue another (only make 2 marines)
- 16 supply
- 17 ref
- (supply counts discontinued from here keep making scvs nonstop)
- factory
- factory
- tech lab on rax
- swap first factory onto rax
- make 1 hellion & get preigniter
- make 1 hellion on second factory

  - clear xelnagas with hellion
- starport
- starport
- supply drop (see faq)
- medivac

  - poke up ramp with a hellion, try to scout composition
  - build order discontinued here, starport production is dependent on opponent's composition

iEchoic's excellent forum post.
http://www.teamliquid.net/forum/viewmessage.php?topic_id=189624

Comment: At first I wanted to berate you for the entire idea of a "counter build," but the more I read your post the more it looks like this has really been thought through.  Its rare to find builds with this much thought put into them, so +1 to you sir.

Comment: Hah, thanks but I can't take much credit for this, iEchoic really perfected it. I've been in search for something different then the typical Marine/Tank or MMM build. When I saw this Day[9] video I was amazed and very taken on how simple yet effective it is. Plus seeing Helions spitting out Blue flame justice is astounding.

Comment: Subleak, u smashed me.. Thanks a lot for a good reading and viewing

Comment: To "counter" at least in some way this 1-2-2 build of iEchoic, after FE the 1st purpose is to build quick Vikings... is it possible? Doing FE u will have gas much later, but u will be able to get 4 gases... In the same time, 1-2-2 doesn't assume not expanding, so he will expand too... ok. Good food for thinking...